# Why does shell printf run strings together when not quoted?

Tags: shell, printf, posix

Can somebody explain this behavior in shell script:

```
TESTVAR='something fishy'
echo $TESTVAR
something fishy
```

But

```
printf "%b" $TESTVAR
somethingfishy            (space removed)
```

While

```
printf "%b" "$TESTVAR"
something fishy
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Nothing bash-specific here; everything described is behavior mandated by the POSIX sh standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is a consequence of two rules:

- When you pass `printf` more arguments than the format string contains placeholders, the format string is repeated until all arguments are consumed. With a format string having only one placeholder, that means it's repeated once per subsequent argument.
- When you don't quote parameter expansions, they undergo word-splitting (creating a separate word for contents on either side of each character in `IFS`) and glob expansion (replacing those words with a list of filenames which they match when interpreted as globs, should any such names exist), thus resulting in a variable number of shell words, each of which is passed as a separate argument to `printf`.

---

Thus, `TESTVAR='something fishy'; echo $TESTVAR`, with a default `IFS`, becomes a precise equivalent to `echo "something" "fishy"`, which prints `something fishy`, because `echo` separates each argument with a space.

By contrast, `printf %b $TESTVAR` becomes `printf %b "something" "fishy"`, which uses `%b` to format `something`, and again to format `fishy`; nothing in there inserts a space, so you don't get any spaces on output. (If instead you'd made it `printf '%b ' $TESTVAR`, you would have seen spaces inserted).

Finally, `printf %b "$TESTVAR"` runs `printf %b "something fishy"`; the space is preserved because it's a literal part of the third argument, so the `%b` format string is only evaluated once, against the entire `something fishy` argument with a space already included.

---

The lesson of this story: **Always quote your expansions.** See also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) describing in detail how `echo $foo` is itself buggy unless quoted as `echo "$foo"`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation